# Создание интервального таймера

Tags: java, java-ee

Через TimerService можно вызвать метод createCalendarTimer который создаст календарный таймер с определенными интервалами которые будут переданы через ScheduleExpression.
Задача состоит в том, что я получаю cron строку делаю её парсинг, в ней передаются секунды через которые должен срабатывать таймер (пример: 10,23,47,81,135), можно ли это задать в ScheduleExpression, чтобы таймер срабатывал через указанные секунды, если да, то как, если нет, есть ли другой способ?

Comment: Создать срабатывание таймера каждую секунду и считать прошедшее время вручную. Чем плох такой метод?

Comment: Хмм, тип каждую секунду срабатывает таймер, проверяется прошло ли 10 или сколько нужно секунд и только тогда выполняется метод, в принципе подходит, но добавляются дополнительные действия и хранить секунды нужно, как то не оч красиво

Comment: Ну это в принципе достаточно распространенный метод, если уж других механизмов нет. Создать отдельный класс для отложенных задач и пускай себе считает прошедшее время, а мы просто добавляем нужную задачу в очередь